# Using GridBagLayout With WeightY Function Splits Rows Instead of Resizing When Window is Resized

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering (as said in the title) if there is any way to resize rows when resizing the window. What happens to me when I use weighty function in GridBagLayout is that the rows split and there becomes space in between them. Is there any way to resize the rows instead of the spacing?

(Sorry if this is a bit unclear; here is a picture of  [what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC1Tk.jpg))

Here is the important part of my code when I tried coding GridBagLayout:

```
JTextField display = new JTextField();//This is the top Text Field as seen in the picture
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(one, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(two, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(three, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(plus, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
panel.add(four, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
panel.add(five, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 1;
panel.add(six, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 1;
panel.add(minus, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 2;
panel.add(seven, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 2;
panel.add(eight, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 2;
panel.add(nine, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 2;
panel.add(multiply, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 3;
panel.add(zero, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 3;
c.gridwidth = 2;
panel.add(equals, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridy = 3;
c.gridwidth = 1;
panel.add(divide, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 4;
panel.add(decimal, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 4;
panel.add(negative, c);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 4;
panel.add(modulus, c);

BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
frame.add(display, bl.NORTH);//This is the top display,not very important.
frame.add(panel, bl.CENTER);
```

Comment: sorry forgot the picture lemme add it

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the image you attached, it seems you're using Java Swing. A little deep dive into the code would be useful(if you can paste the code here).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! My mistake was that I typed `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` so that it only resized horizontally and not vertically. What i figured out (it is very obvious but I couldn't think of it when I posted the question) is that I use `c.fill = GridBadConstraints.BOTH` so that it resizes both vertically and horizontally.